# Sporadic SSL error 140940F6 (unknown alert type) when using SSL_shutdown on server

Tags: sockets, openssl

I have relatively simple multi-threaded SSL server and clients, similar to web server/client.

This entire setup works mostly fine, however clients sporadically fail on SSL handshake with the following error:

```
SSL Error 336150774: error:140940F6:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:unknown alert type
```

This happens seemingly randomly, once per 20-100 connections, and subsequent re-connections succeed.
Server uses OpenSSL 1.0.1i which I compiled myself from official source (on Windows), with no customizations of any kind. 
We have different clients, including non-OpenSSL one, which exhibit the same behavior. There are no errors on server side from what I can tell. Web search for these errors didn't turn up anything useful so far. If there's only one client at a time, the error doesn't happen.

Things I have tried so far:

- varying SSL options such as session caching
- CRYPTO_set_locking_callback on both server and clients is already set (without that, server generally falls apart at some point on heavy load)
- serializing SSL_accept and SSL_shutdown on server, so that only one happens at a time
- varying protocol options (all defaults, TLSv1 only, etc)

None of that helps. The clients still get the above error sporadically. 
The only thing that does help is omitting SSL_shutdown() on server side. 
That eliminates the error, however that results in slow but steady leak of handles on the server, which otherwise doesn't happen.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you make sure that only a single thread cares about one SSL object, i.e. that you never do I/O at the same time on the same SSL connection from multiple threads? See https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, once accept() succeeds, a new thread is spawned for that new socket and all I/O on it happens in that thread only, including initial SSL_accept(), read/write and SSL_shutdown() at the end